# Calling .mouseenter( ) is working even though .click( ) won't trigger animation

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

In HTML, I have a button with the id of "submit1"

```
<div id="first"> 
    <form>
        <input type="radio" name="school" value="pitt">Pitt<br>
        <input type="radio" name="school" value="memphis">Memphis<br>
        <button id="submit1">Submit</button>
    </form>
</div>
```

Now in Jquery, I try to use a .click() to trigger the div "first" to fadeOut, like so:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#submit1').click(function(){
         $('#first').fadeOut('slow');
     });
 });
```

Weirdly enough, nothing happens when I click submit. I thought maybe it wasn't calling my .js file, but alas, when I change it to a .mouseenter( ), it works perfectly to trigger a fadeOut of the div.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('#submit1').mouseenter(function(){
    $('#first').fadeOut('slow');
});
});
```

I saw an old Stack Overflow post where they used alert instead of an animation, so I tried that too during debugging and it still worked. It is literally just animations that seem to break things (tried .slideToggle, .slideDown, etc. just to check). Thanks!

Comment: use this inside button tag type="submit" and try

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since the submit button is inside a form element, the default click behavior is to submit the form to the server. Internally, the JS is being called but this also causes the whole page to refresh so you don't see the animation happening. In order to prevent this, change your code to prevent the default submit behavior:

```
$('#submit1').click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('#first').fadeOut('slow');
});
```

Comment: @darkginger its working right then approve his/her answer ..!